# how to automate the back out queue clearance in WMQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

in production support i have to delete every day messages from 100 of queues from different queue managers in WMQ (WMQ IBM) manually. can it be automated such that by running a script message in back out queue should be deleted .?

my requirements : 
1. by giving queue name i should be able to delete message from queue and date should be  the selecting criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite an exhaustive list of possible solutions here:

http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=1616

You should take a look at the options with the Java or C program, by modifying the program you can implement your 2nd requirement to delete messages sent on a given date.

Answer (score 0):

> my requirements : 1. by giving queue name i should be able to delete
>   message from queue and date should be the selecting criteria.

If you need to delete messages older than a particular date then the blog posting will not help.  You will need to use a program like [MQ Batch Toolkit](http://www.capitalware.com/mqbt_overview.html).
i.e.  To delete messages older 2 days then you would issue:

```
mqbt ClearQByTime -p MQA1 -q TEST.Q1 -d 2
```

If you need to run it on a daily basis then put the command into the scheduler on the server.